# Insects or Birds covering least distance but most wing moves

Tags: entomology, ornithology

I was in search in of list or detail about Insects and Birds which move their wings most but cover least distance.

I know that in insects house fly moves its wings about 200/sec and covers 5mph (about 7.3 feet) distance and in birds Hummingbird moves its wings about 80/sec and covers 60mph (about 88 feet) distance, but I am in search of about 10 in each insects and birds. And also about their heart beats.

If you have combine list, it will be much appreciated. If you know any book or website about same topic it will much helpful.

Comment: When hummingbirds are hovering, they go 0 distance at ~80 Hz flapping frequency and ~1200 bpm heartrate. http://www.hummingbirds.net/about.html#wingbeat